# split front end and back end

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, split-stacks

Split stack development is an architecture pattern that separates front-end and back-end development into two separate “stacks” which function independently and communicate through an API ... for more info https://medium.com/@MentallyFriendly/split-stack-development-a-model-for-modern-applications-d7b9abb47bd5

so, we need help with that , how we can implement this ?? what type of API we should use ??? ...any resources ... any helping articles ... etc.

we are using AngularJs for front end and Asp.net core for back end.

Answer (score 0):

Write restful API route on your ASP.net and deploy it on server. Use library like Axios to make API request in your AngularJs to that ASP.net server. That's what two separate stack mean.

Comment: actually this is what we already did , but we need to deploy them on  completely different app's so that they can communicate through an API .
 read this article for more info  .
https://medium.com/@MentallyFriendly/split-stack-development-a-model-for-modern-applications-d7b9abb47bd5